# Google play services leak in Main

Tags: android, google-play-services

While trying to implement ads into my app I am getting this error upon showing the ad.

The only thing I've added to my app in regards to Google play services is importing into gradle and adding to my manifest. I could not find any information on initialization or any other info where I have to add any code to my main.

Here is the log

```
06-26 21:53:31.062 E/ActivityThread(15754): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.intellidev.bitrich.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.common.zza@5db576d that was originally bound here
```

**update**
Seems I need to initialize play services builder then connect. However the only reason it is implemented is to work with supersonic ads. So here less my problem on hpw to implement it.

Comment: GPS version? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Is there literally no code written mentioning "ServiceConnection" in your code? Can you share the snippets in which "ServiceConnection" is mentioned?

Comment: No there is literally no code written anywhere other than gradle and manifest. I know this must be the cause of my errors. I need to connect Google play and retrieve user advertising id

Answer (score 0):

Your supersonic ad sdk is causing the bug. The ad view connects to play services and does not disconnect properly.

Comment: This i know but it does not tell me how to fix it.

Comment: If the bug is caused by the ad view it's not yours to fix, you should contact supersonic or use another Ad SDK.

Comment: The SDK does work as it's implemented in hundrerds of apps

Comment: Maybe hundreds of apps are leaking, I've seen a lot of ad and analytics SDKs doing crazy stuff... Anyway, the exact cause of the problem is when you create a GoogleApiClient and you connect, you need to call disconnect() on it before the Activity is destroyed or it will leak.

Comment: Also have an activity leak while using supersonic SDK. http://www.alexandroid.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SuperSonicLeak.jpg